# Deserializing a json array of lists

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

How can I deserialize a Json Array of Lists?

**Example:**

```
[
  [
    "id",
    "date",
    "time",
    "start_time",
    "end_time",
    "sc_name"
  ],
  [
    121329387,
    "2022-05-07",
    null,
    null,
    null
  ],
  [
    123863076,
    "2022-12-05",
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
]
```

How can I convert the above string to List type

Comment: What "LIst type"?

Comment: You would need to write some kind of parser. To C# that string is just a string. There's no list of any kind.

Comment: Missing code to show what you tried so far. Try searching for tokenizing and regex.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Well, to be fair, it's a list of `char`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: OK, if we *really* want to pick nits here, technically it's at best an `IEnumerable<char>`. (I guess `IReadOnlyList<char>` came too late to the party to be considered for addition, while implementing `IList<char>` would have been too burdensome/confusing since strings are immutable.) It is a "list" in the abstract sense, I suppose. In any case none of this is helpful to the OP. :P

Comment: Lists of Lists are usually symptoms of an incorrect object model. Consider [creating a list of a class that implements your model behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt).

Answer (score 1):

If "List type" means `List<List<int>>`, you can `Split` *two times*:

1. By `][` to have lines
2. By `,` to have integer numbers

**Code:**

```
string a = "[1,2,3][1,3,4][1,1,1]";

List<List<int>> result = a
  .Split("][")
  .Select(line => line
     .Trim(']', '[')
     .Split(',')
     .Select(number => int.Parse(number))
     .ToList())
  .ToList();
```

To obtain separate list, just address `result` with the requied index:

```
// {1, 3, 4}
List<int> secondLine = result[1];
```